# Sniff multiple serial ports simultaneously with socat

Tags: linux, serial-port, sniffing, sniffer, socat

I'm trying to record multiple serial ports simultaneously, I am able to log once at a time, but when I launch a new socat, the old process is terminated.

This are the commands I want to execute, just a simple socat sniff to file.

```
socat -lf /dev/stdout -x -s 2> USB1.log /dev/ttyUSB1,echo=0 - &
socat -lf /dev/stdout -x -s 2> USB2.log /dev/ttyUSB2,echo=0 - &
socat -lf /dev/stdout -x -s 2> USB3.log /dev/ttyUSB3,echo=0 - &
```

I'm able to read all simultaneously using [jpnevulator](https://github.com/snarlistic/jpnevulator), but I believe is interfering with the communication of the devices as they suddenly have communication failures, and when I close the jpnevulator the communication improves. The command I've tried with is `jpnevulator --tty /dev/ttyUSB1 --read --timing-print`

Comment: If you're logging to files, why don't you read from the files with tail or something like that?

Comment: I can't, I can only have 1 instance of socat running, when I run the second instance, the 1st one is terminated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apparently is because trying to use `/dev/stdout` multiple times with the `-lf` option. Instead, you must use PTY as intermediaries.

```
socat -xs /dev/ttyUSB1,raw  PTY,link=/tmp/USB1,raw,echo=0 2 >> USB1.log &
socat -xs /dev/ttyUSB2,raw  PTY,link=/tmp/USB2,raw,echo=0 2 >> USB2.log &
socat -xs /dev/ttyUSB3,raw  PTY,link=/tmp/USB3,raw,echo=0 2 >> USB3.log &
```